# Update the app's Live Tile without user launching app

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I want to have the feature that apps like Weather have - they have their Live Tile updated even before a user launches them. And even after a user launches and closes them.

At first I thought they simply launch on startup, but checking Task Manager's startup tab (sent there from msconfig's startup tab) didn't show Weather. Also, that wouldn't solve the question of why closing the app doesn't stop the tile's updating.
So I checked  [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx) and it seems that the correct way is by using Periodic notifications. But those require a url. I want the app to locally create the content.

So how do I get that functionality without a url?

Information I've found while searching for this (including other questions here) tend to refer to Windows 8 or Windows Phone. (And one of the ways seems to be limited to running every 30 minutes.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `BackgroundTasks`. You can use a `TimeTrigger` to run the task periodically. Note that in Windows 10, your app no longer needs to be on the lock screen for time trigger background tasks (that requirement only exists for Windows 8.1 desktop/tablet).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt186458.aspx

Comment: Note the lock screen requirement was removed in Win10, but the docs are still copied from Win8. We will get them updated.

Comment: Even better. Thanks @PeterTorr-MSFT